# react carousel with 100% width

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have below code for carousel in react.

```
<Carousel activeIndex={index} onSelect={handleSelect} >
    <Carousel.Item>
        <img
            className="d-block w-100"
            height="500"
            src="/images/taj.jpg"
            alt="First slide"
        />
        <Carousel.Caption>
            <h3>First slide label</h3>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
        </Carousel.Caption>
    </Carousel.Item>
    <Carousel.Item>
        <img
            className="d-block w-100"
            height="500"
            src="/images/moon.jpg"
            alt="Second slide"
        />

        <Carousel.Caption>
            <h3>Second slide label</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </Carousel.Caption>
    </Carousel.Item>
    <Carousel.Item>
        <img
            className="d-block w-100"
            height="500"
            src="/images/pebbles.jpg"
            alt="Third slide"
        />

        <Carousel.Caption>
            <h3>Third slide label</h3>
            <p>
                Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.
            </p>
        </Carousel.Caption>
    </Carousel.Item>
</Carousel>
```

I have tried wrapping Carousel in a div and setting the width to 100% on the div and width attribute of img tag but still there is small gap left on both sides of the image I have highlighted the gap in yellow on the below screenshot, please suggest how to remove this extra white space.

[image]

Comment: try inspect the element from dev tools and check if any padding .

Comment: thank you for your response, I don't see any padding in  the inspect element

Comment: well if you can add codesandbox showcasing you code so we can help you better.

Comment: I got this issue, I am sorry I didn't post my index.js where I am calling this in a div  with container fluid, as per the documentation container fluid should acquire 100% width but fluid was causing this extra space not sure the reason, would you please help me to understand why fluid is behaving unexpectedly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default every bootstrap container has extra `15px` horizontal padding that's why your content not taking full width so you can remove this padding by using bootstrap class `p-0`.
here the full example:

```css
.container{
height:100px;
background-color:blue
}
.container-fluid{
height:100px;
background-color:red
}
.content{
width:100%;
height:100%;
color:white;
background-color :rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
<div class="content">container default padding</div></div>
<div class="container-fluid"><div class="content">container fluid default padding</div></div>
<div class="container p-0">
<div class="content">container without padding</div></div></div>
<div class="container-fluid p-0"><div class="content">container fluid without padding</div></div>
```

Comment: This solved my another problem also, thank you so much for your help.